# Solve the Initial Value Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I split the equation and got y+1 dy = xysinxdx, then I divided the right side by y to get 1 + (1/y) = xsinx dx. I took the integrals of both sides and got y + lny = -xcosx + sinx + c.

I don't really know how to get rid of the lny to isolate y by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct and exponentating you have:

$$
ye^y=e^{\sin x-x\cos x+c}
$$

and the explicit solution can be done only using [Lambert W Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

$$
y=W(e^{\sin x-x\cos x+c})
$$
Where the $W$ function is defined    as: $W(ze^z)=z$